# Google Places API not displaying website (URL)

Tags: google-places-api

I am looking for business name, addy, phone number and business URL within the Google Places API.  My test url string is **https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Grand+Rapids+Michigan&url=true&sensor=true&key=MYKEY** I'm not receiving phone number or Business website (URL). However the businesses that are being returned have that info in the google listing.  I'm new to this and just trying to get a handle on how to do the search query.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe phone number and website URL are only available in [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) requests.  You would take the `reference` from the results of the `textsearch` and send it in the `details` request.